# Debug symbols on Yocto

Tags: c++, gdb, yocto

I'm trying to debug a c++ code with gdb on a target platform which run with an OS created with Yocto and comparing results with my laptop.
All the package have default compilation flags (no O3 or so)

**Setup**:

- Yocto 2.2
- Target: rpi3-64
- gdb 7.11.1
- CMake Flags in my c++ packages: `EXTRA_OECMAKE = " -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"`
- Yocto debug flags in local.conf:

  ```
  INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
  INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
  DEBUG_BUILD = "1"
  EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " dbg-pkgs"
  ```

Debug symbols are loaded when starting gdb.

On my laptop, using `info locals`, I can see the variables and their values. On my target platform, I sometimes get values, but also symbols like:

```
_M_impl
_M_key_compare
_M_string_length
```

and sometimes other type of output:

```
rotation_ = {<Eigen::RotationBase<Eigen::Rotation2D<double>, 2>> = {<No data fields>}
```

Is there something else that needs to be done on Yocto to enable debugging?

EDIT: I tried a minimal C++ example, it seems the std library doesn't have the debug symbols.

Comment: are you using gdb remote?

Comment: I'm doing it on the target machine

Comment: try adding `INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"`

Comment: thanks, i also thought it would solve it, but it's already done, as mentioned in the description

Comment: Could it be the debug symbols of libstdc++ need to be enable at compilation time?

Comment: @DavidBensoussan I don't think that it will help to solve your problem, but you have a "syntax" error during append of image features. The `_append` operator concatenates without space, so your EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES variable probably has an invalid entry. The correct line is `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " dbg-pkgs"`. You can check the content of any variable via `bitbake -e <your_image>`.

Comment: @TomasNovotny, it was actuallya typo here.